# Inverse Fourier Transform of product of two functions in $L^p$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, convolution

If $f \in L^{q}$ for all $1 \leq q \leq \infty$ and $g \in L^{p}$ for some $1<p \leq 2$, how is it possible to get that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f \mathcal{F}(g))(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}f*g(x)?
\end{equation}
I know the result for $g \in \mathscr{S}$ using tempered distributions but I can't figure it out in this case. I don't even know if this accounts make sense in this spaces.

Comment: $\mathcal{F}(g)\in L^{p'} $ where $p'={p\over p-1}.$  Hence $f\mathcal{F}(g)\in L^q$ for $q<p'.$  In particular the product belongs to $L^2.$

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I couldn't understand what's the consequence.